# May static and non static variables in class have the same name according to DartLangSpec-v2.2

Tags: dart

A class has several scopes:

• A type-parameter scope, which is empty if the class is not generic (14).
The enclosing scope of the type-parameter scope of a class is the enclosing
scope of the class declaration. 
• A static scope. The enclosing scope of the static scope of a class is the
type parameter scope (14) of the class. 
• An instance scope. The enclosing scope of a class’ instance scope is the
class’ static scope.
From https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf page 27

```
class Foo {
    static var x;
    var x;
}
```

I think according to the document it should work. But getting compilation error. Is my understanding about scope wrong? If I am wrong can you please clear me about the difference between scope and namespace in dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scopes/name-spaces are pretty much as you expect. They are mainly used for *lookups*, not conflict resolution. Most conflict resolutions are handled explicitly in the specification in other places (although a few are just handled by the rule that you can't introduce the same name into a scope twice).

For example, there are more restrictions on classes than just the scope based ones, including:

- A class must not declare two members with the same basename unless one is a setter and the other is a getter.
- A class must not declare a static member with the same basename as an inherited member.
- A class must not declare a type parameter with the same name as the class.
- A class must not declare a member with a basename that is the same as the name of the class or of a type parameter of the class.

Your example fails the first item.